# Dysfunctional Clone

Tags: database, ssms, sspi

A Database Server has been cloned. The Operating System is `"Microsoft Windows XP Professional Version 2002 Service Pack 3"`. The Query Environment is `"Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Studio 10.0.4000.0"`.

After cloning, the following behaviour has been noticed. While attempting to connect from outside the machine, yet within the same domain, the following error message can be read: `"Cannot generate SSPI context. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)"`.

From within the machine, it is possible to connect to the Database Server using the `"Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Studio"` Query Environment.

However, when attempting to run the `SQLCmd` command line tool, the following error is displayed:

```
C:\<Directory>>SQLCmd -S DBA2\<Instance> -i C:\<Directory>\<FileName>.SQL
HResult 0x80090322, Level 16, State 1
SQL Server Network Interfaces: The target principal name is incorrect.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : Cannot generate SSPI context.
```

The `ServicePrincipalNames` are set the following way:

```
C:\PROGRA~1\SUPPOR~1>setspn DBA2
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=DBA2,CN=Computers,DC=<Company>,DC=com:
VProRecovery Backup Exec System Recovery Agent 7.0/DBA2.<Company>.com
HOST/DBA2
HOST/DBA2.<Company>.com
```

While running the `"C:\PROGRA~1\SUPPOR~1\ADSIEDIT.MSC"` Support Tool from the Microsoft Windows XP Professional compact disk, we can see below the `"ADSI Edit \ Domain [<Site>.<Company>.com] \ DC=<Company>,DC=com"` path the `"CN=Computers"` leaf. In its `"Properties"` dialog box, inside the `"Security"` tab, below the `"Group or user names:"` list, there is the `"SELF"` entry. On pressing the `"Advanced"` button, the `"Advanced Security Settings for Computers"` dialog box is generated. On the `"Permissions"` tab, under the `"Permission entries:"` list, there also is an entry with the Name `"SELF"`. By pressing the `"Edit..."` button, the `"Permission Entry for Computers"` dialog box is displayed. On its `"Properties"` tab, in the `"Permissions:"` list, there are no entries for the `"Read ServicePrincipalName"` permission and for the `"Write ServicePrincipalName"` permission.

This might be the reason why the following command fails:

```
C:\PROGRA~1\SUPPOR~1>setspn -r DBA2
Registering ServicePrincipalNames for CN=DBA2,CN=Computers,DC=<Company>,DC=com
HOST/DBA2.<Company>
HOST/DBA2
Failed to assign SPN to account 'CN=DBA2,CN=Computers,DC=<Company>,DC=com', 0x2098
```

Even if there were permissions in place for resetting the `ServicePrincipalName` on the cloned Database Server, would that solve the connection both from `SQLCmd` and from outside the machine, within the same domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, yes, that solved the problem after the right permissions were set in the right place.

The `ServicePrincipalNames` had to be set on the `SQL` user, as follows:

```
C:\PROGRA~1\SUPPOR~1>setspn -a mssqlsvc/dba2:1433 <Company>\<UserName>
Registering ServicePrincipalNames for CN=<UserName>,OU=Reporting Security,OU=Security Groups,OU=Romania,DC=<Company>,DC=com
        mssqlsvc/dba2:1433
Updated object

C:\PROGRA~1\SUPPOR~1>setspn -a mssqlsvc/dba2.<Company>.com:1433 <Company>\<UserName>
Registering ServicePrincipalNames for CN=<UserName>,OU=Reporting Security,OU=Security Groups,OU=Romania,DC=<Company>,DC=com
        mssqlsvc/dba2.<Company>.com:1433
Updated object

C:\PROGRA~1\SUPPOR~1>setspn -l dba2
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=DBA2,OU=Romania Machines,OU=Romania,DC=<Company>,DC=com:
    VProRecovery Backup Exec System Recovery Agent 7.0/DBA2.<Company>.com
    HOST/DBA2
    HOST/DBA2.<Company>.com

C:\PROGRA~1\SUPPOR~1>setspn -l <UserName>
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=<UserName>,OU=Reporting Security,OU=Security Groups,OU=Romania,DC=<Company>,DC=com:
    MSSQLSvc/DBA2.<Company>.com:<Company>_RO
    mssqlsvc/dba2.<Company>.com:1433
    mssqlsvc/dba2:1433
```

Hopefully this might help somebody who could stumble into the same problem.